# Append a totals row and/or column to a data.frame in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, tidyr, janitor

Previously, I have used the `adorn_totals` function from the `janitor` package to add row and columns totals to a data.frame. The content of the data.frame was count, so that was fine:

```
RegionSize
   size KUALA LUMPUR OTHERS PENANG SELANGOR DARUL EHSAN TOTAL
   tiny           20      3      1                    0    24
  small          164    120     20                   90   394
 medium          100     69      0                    0   169
    big            0    293    106                    0   399
  TOTAL          284    485    127                   90   986
```

Now I am working on a data.frame, where each cell is a proportion. I need to have the total row and also column, but the `adorn_totals` cannot be used in that case, because the order of operations return wrong values.

So I have three separate tables:

```
Summary
    size KUALA LUMPUR   OTHERS  PENANG SELANGOR DARUL EHSAN
1   tiny        0.000    0.000   0.000                0.000
2  small      435.344  245.598 333.317              272.342
3 medium      187.874 9656.649   0.000                0.000
4    big        0.000  116.861 138.366                0.000


RegionTotals
     experience              region1
1:      156.523               PENANG
2:      272.342 SELANGOR DARUL EHSAN
3:      343.998         KUALA LUMPUR
4:      296.601               OTHERS

SizeTotals
     experience   size
1:        0.000   tiny
2:      348.692  small
3:      136.207    big
4:      223.415 medium

overallTotal
     experience 
1:      276.613
```

How can i achieve the following result, considering that the regions and sizes may change? For example sometimes i will not have the region "OTHERS" or the size "BIG" depending on the data that i get. How can I achieve this:

```
Summary
    size KUALA LUMPUR   OTHERS  PENANG SELANGOR DARUL EHSAN TOTAL
1   tiny        0.000    0.000   0.000                0.000   0.000
2  small      435.344  245.598 333.317              272.342 348.692
3 medium      187.874 9656.649   0.000                0.000 223.415
4    big        0.000  116.861 138.366                0.000 136.207
5. TOTAL      343.998  296.601 156.523              272.342 276.613
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use *rbind* to add a row to your data frame, e.g.:

```
total <- c(size="TOTAL", apply(x[,-1], FUN=sum, MAR=2)
rbind(x, total)
```

In the same way, you can use *cbind* to add a column. The only tricky part is that you must omit the non-numeric columns from the summation: that's why I use the index -1, which removes the first column.